# Optimize distance calculations using google maps with multiple locations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to calculate the distance between the user and the company. I'm able to do it now when calculating only the distance between 1 user and 1 business. But on the search view of my app, I would have to calculate the distance between 1 user and multiple business.

For example, the user is logged and have a valid address. Then, the user enters the search page to look for a store to buy some shoes. On this page the results needs to have the distance between the user location and all the business on the result. So I would have something like this:

```
user <--> businness 1 = 800m
user <--> businness 2 = 1.650m
user <--> businness 3 = 5.2m
user <--> businness 4 = 1.2m
```

I'm able to make this calculation, but with the method I'm using it's not fast. It takes too much time to make all the calculations.

This is the code I'm using:

```
function checkDistance() {

    var splitUser   = user.map.split(','),
        userLat     = parseFloat(splitUser[0]),
        userLng     = parseFloat(splitUser[1]),

        splitBusi   = busi.map.split(','),
        busiLat      = parseFloat(splitBusi[0]),
        busiLng      = parseFloat(splitBusi[1]);

    var origin      = new google.maps.LatLng(userLat,userLng),
        destin      = new google.maps.LatLng(busiLat,busiLng);

    var service     = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
        service.getDistanceMatrix({
            origins: [origin],
            destinations: [destin],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, callback);

    function callback(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
            var origins = response.originAddresses;
            for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
                var results = response.rows[i].elements;
                for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
                    var distance        = results[j].distance.text,
                        finalDistance   = distance.split(' ')[0].replace(',', '.');
                    return finalDistance;
                };
            };
        };
    };
}
```

Is there a way to optimize this calculation? Or even other method to do it?
Because I would have to run this function for each business, and each time this function runs, it takes up 1-2 seconds to return the value.
I'm working on an AngularJs 1.x app, so it could be anything on JS or Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have to run the callback for each business?

DistanceMatrixService is exactly what you need, but you must use it properly.

You may define up to 25 businesses in a single request and you'll get the distances from the user to all businesses with a single response.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix